# While user oledb open excel file ,throw an SEHException

Tags: excel, iis

I write an code to open Excel file and read the info and insert SQL DB
It's normal few days ago.
But today when I use the function via internet, it throw error.
But I didn't modify my code.
And I debug at Server localhost, it's Normal, 
Is this IIS server's error? Or I must correct my code?
please help me thanks!!

following is my error message and my code

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection connection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.OleDb.12.0;" + "data source=" + FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0; HDR=YES; IMEX=1'");

connection.Open();
```

The error is 0x80004005 "Unspecified Error" [Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vx1W8.png)

Comment: It's a really unhelpful error message.  My money would be on a missing or corrupted Excel file; or on a file permissions issue.  What is the value of `FileName` when you call the function?

Comment: My FileName is the file's path like \\192.168.30.12\Doc\abc.xlsx
The file is on the file server, not on the local

Comment: So that is a [private network address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network).  If you are trying to get to it from the internet, it's not going to work.

Comment: Yes, but we use the web just in the private network address.
My Web address is 192.168.30.75 and file server is 192.168.30.12
It's a internal web